# IMPROPER RESOURCE ACCESS AUTHERIZATION

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

We are getting `IMPROPER RESOURCE ACCESS AUTHORIZATION` issue while review the java code through `Checkmarx` (security vulnerability code review tool). Getting issue from the below code snippet.

Code -  DAO Class

```
data = repository.findById(id);
```

We are using JPA repository and spring boot technology.

I tried with all spring JPA security but did not find any solution.

Comment: Maybe you should check if the "id" variable is SQL Injection free.

Comment: did you solve the issue?